# Is it possible to Add 3rd party library(.a files) to cordova project?

Tags: xcode, cordova

I've tried adding [this debenu library](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/ios-pdf-sdk/) to a pure native iOS project and it works.

**Problem:**

However when I try to add it to a cardova xcode porject, it gives me these errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_CTFontCollectionCreateFromAvailableFonts", referenced from:
>         ScreenFonts(int, int) in libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a(DebenuPDFLibraryFontConst.o)
>     "_CTFontCollectionCreateMatchingFontDescriptors", referenced from:
>         ScreenFonts(int, int) in libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a(DebenuPDFLibraryFontConst.o)
>     "_CTFontDescriptorCopyAttribute", referenced from:
>         ScreenFonts(int, int) in libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a(DebenuPDFLibraryFontConst.o)
>     "std::runtime_error::what() const", referenced from:
>         vtable for fmt::FormatError in libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a(format.o)
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::at(unsigned long) const", referenced from:
>         TPDFIndObj::IsStream(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const*, int&, int&) in libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a(DebenuPDFLibraryDocument.o)
>     "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::find(char, unsigned long) const", referenced from:

**This are the steps I did:**

1. Create a new cordova Xcode project
2. Add the l​ibxml2.dylib​library to the "Link binary with libraries" list in the target's Build Phases
   project settings
3. Add the D​ebenuPDFLibraryCPiOSObjC1115.h ​header file to the project
4. Add the static library libDebenuPDFLibraryCPiOS1115.a to the project
5. Add the ­​lc++​ option to the “Otherlinkerflags” optionintheprojectsettings
6. Add a button and link it to an IBAction called buttonClick,
7. Compile with 141 errors

Answer (score 0):

Got it just need to import the core text framework